# node.js npm ping error times.push(parseFloat(match

Tags: node.js, npm, ping

Detalle de error
C:\util\Node\Examples\Ping\node_modules\ping\lib\parser\win.js:60
        this._times.push(parseFloat(match[1], 10));
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at WinParser._processBody (C:\util\Node\Examples\Ping\node_modules\ping\lib\parser\win.js:60:42)
    at WinParser.parser.eat (C:\util\Node\Examples\Ping\node_modules\ping\lib\parser\base.js:125:14)
    at C:\util\Node\Examples\Ping\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:76:21
    at Function.*.each.*.forEach (C:\util\Node\Examples\Ping\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:186:9)
    at ChildProcess. (C:\util\Node\Examples\Ping\node_modules\ping\lib\ping-promise.js:76:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:318:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:927:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution
Modify the win.js file
The error is due to the fact that in the code it looks for the text 'ms' and when it does not get results it gets an undefined in the variable' timeKVP ', sometimes when the answer is very fast the text does not contain this text but if the' m ', for this reason we modify line 55 as follows:

https://github.com/danielzzz/node-ping/issues/112#issuecomment-603567119